# How to specify the specific packages for the 'jacoco-check'?

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

My project is built using Maven. I use the 'Jacoco' plugin to perform quality checks.

For a project I would like to check the test coverage on line basis. I would like to check the line coverage only for only 3 packages. How can I specify this check?

I tried 'including' a number of packages, but that does not work. 
I also tried to include the root package level and exclude a number of other packages. Also not working.

How can I have the package A, B and C checked? See my example below:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.9</version>
    <executions>
      ...
      <execution>
        <id>jacoco-check</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <rule>
              <element>PACKAGE</element>
              <includes>
                <include>nl.abc.xyz.package-a.**</include>
                <include>nl.abc.xyz.package-b.**</include>
                <include>nl.abc.xyz.package-c.**</include>
              </includes>
              ... 
              <limits>
                <limit>
                  <counter>LINE</counter>
                  <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                  <minimum>0.30</minimum>
                </limit>
              </limits>
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`includes` and `excludes` of `rule` are about `name` of the corresponding element.
In case of `<element>PACKAGE</element>` they are about package name.
And therefore

> ```
>           <includes>
>             <include>nl.abc.xyz.package-a.**</include>
>             <include>nl.abc.xyz.package-b.**</include>
>             <include>nl.abc.xyz.package-c.**</include>
>           </includes>
> ```

Matches for example package named `nl.abc.xyz.package-a.something`, but doesn't match `nl.abc.xyz.package-a`.

Given

`src/main/java/org/example/a/A.java`

```
package org.example.a;

public class A {
}
```

`src/main/java/org/example/a/B.java`

```
package org.example.b;

public class B {
}
```

`src/test/java/ExampleTest.java`

```
public class ExampleTest {
  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
    new org.example.a.A();
  }
}
```

and `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>report</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>check</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <rule>
                  <element>PACKAGE</element>
                  <includes>
                    <include>org.example.b</include>
                  </includes>
                  <limits>
                    <limit>
                      <counter>LINE</counter>
                      <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                      <minimum>0.90</minimum>
                    </limit>
                  </limits>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Execution of `mvn verify` will fail as expected

```
[INFO] --- jacoco-maven-plugin:0.8.2:check (check) @ example ---
[INFO] Loading execution data file /private/tmp/j/target/jacoco.exec
[INFO] Analyzed bundle 'example' with 2 classes
[WARNING] Rule violated for package org.example.b: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.90
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and after replacement of `<include>org.example.b</include>` on `<include>org.example.*</include>` will also fail with the same message, because `org.example.*` matches `org.example.b`. And after replacement on `<include>org.example.a</include>` will succeed as expected.

[image]

Comment: ** is for traversal of directories and it's important and different than * which is for wild card character for file names.