# Test Cucumber Coverage

Tags: java, testing, cucumber

I'm looking for a way to get Coverage of my Cucumber ( Funct Tests ) Same as Unit tests. using jaccoco plugin.

the idea is to make a quality Gate on my Cucumber tests coverage in my project

Comment: May be this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58536904/code-coverage-for-cucumber-tests-using-jacoco